# Cannot download ojdbc specific jar from nexus using gradle

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, nexus3

Currently I am learning Nexus and gradle integration and stuck with one issue.

One file OJDBC14.jar is has already been uploaded on nexus earlier. So when we mentioned that jar in build.gradle dependency, it downloads from nexus.
[OJDBC14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S42iH.png)

```
dependencies {
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.9-rc'
compile 'ojdbc:ojdbc:14'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.8.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.0'}
```

Recently I have uploaded new jar file OJDBC8.jar on nexus using UI but build.gradle cannot download that file from nexus.
[OJDBC8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffVfl.png)

```
dependencies {
compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.9-rc'
compile 'ojdbc:ojdbc:14'
compile 'ojdbc:ojdbc:8'
testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.5'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:4.0.0'
compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:4.0.0'
compile 'com.aventstack:extentreports:3.1.2'
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.11.3'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
compile 'com.sparkjava:spark-core:2.8.0'
compile group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-math3', version: '3.0'}
```

I checked the .gradle log but it does not showing any error message.

Is there any other settings to do when we upload the jar using UI?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to add two different versions of the same module `ojdbc:ojdbc` for the same configuration `compile`, but this is not supported by Gradle, see more details about dependencies resolution  [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/introduction_dependency_management.html#sec:dependency_resolution). In your case, unless you change the default resolution strategy, the latest version of this module will be used, so version 14.

So I think your issue is not connected to this particular library version 8 in your Nexus: you can try to remove/comment the dependency `compile 'ojdbc:ojdbc:14'` and keep only `compile 'ojdbc:ojdbc:14'`:  Gradle should be able to download/use this version 8.

Comment: Thank you so much @M.Ricciuiti. I added new jar with updated version number and now it is working fine.